# focus() not working with input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a component in Angular where I have an html canvas and when I click on it I need to place an input element over the canvas so the user can write some text and press enter, and then the text will be copied to the canvas.

So everything kind of works at the moment but I wanted that when the user clicks in the canvas, at the same time the input is placed in the canvas, the focus is set on it, so the user can write immediately instead of having to click on the input again.

I reduced the problem to the minimum, so I have now a simple canvas and an input element, and when I click on the canvas I want to set the focus on the input, but it does not work. Can anybody help me out?

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/danaya/56e7zxg3/), and this is the js

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#my-canvas');

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  const input = document.querySelector('.canvas__input');
  console.log(input);
  input.focus();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MDN doc:

> If you call HTMLElement.focus() from a mousedown event handler, you
>   must call event.preventDefault() to keep the focus from leaving the
>   HTMLElement.

So please try this:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#my-canvas');

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const input = document.querySelector('.canvas__input');
  console.log(input);
  input.focus();
});
```